# How to deploy a Spring Integration app in Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications, spring-integration

I've gone through the "[Spring Integration in 10 minutes](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/02/13/982/)" tutorial for setting up a basic Spring Integration application.  I'd like to deploy this application in Tomcat and have the input channel live on the server and send the output back to a client, but I'm having a difficult time finding any examples of this.

Could anyone provide me with either some links to a tutorial for how to do this or any other kind of guidance?  All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the response I got from the Spring Integration forums:

Hi

First - try building simple Spring MVC application (no Spring-Int!) - this will get you know how to integrate Java Web Applications (particularily web.xml file) with Spring Framework (spring context XMLs). Then try adding Spring Integration beans (channels, filters, ...) to Spring configuration.

The simplest scenario is this:

- configure DispatcherServlet in web.xml
- build simple Spring MVC Controller
- add Spring Integration beans to DispatcherServlet's XML configuration
- inject channel to controller and use it

This is rough tutorial on how to send messages in response of client's HTTP request.

Then you can try using Spring-Integration web services support where you can configure everything without writing controller's code.

So - first try some Spring MVC samples and then try Spring Integration

good luck
Grzegorz Grzybek

[Source](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=267674#post267674)

Comment: Don't forget to configure a ContextLoaderListener for your application context, otherwise your DispatcherServlet won't wake up until a web request arrives. (May be ok if you only use HTTP inbound to trigger your integration, not ok if you use something else like JMS.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the [Spring Integration forum](http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=42)?