# Best way to make synchronous calls between Java EE apps

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi, message-queue, esb

I have two Java EE web apps that are going to be published on the same physical server, but on different network addresses.

**APP A**: Listens to a port on a public IP address and makes synchronous invocations to app B if necessary.

**APP B**: Listens to a port on a private IP address and makes synchronous invocations to app A if necessary.

[image]

For connecting APP A with APP B, I am considering the following alternatives.

- RMI
- Message Queue
- Lightweight ESB

Please tell me if you see any clear advantage supported by facts on any of them, or if there's another technology I should consider.

Comment: MQ and most/all ESB's would be considered asynchronous...

Comment: Yes, but you could achieve synchronization through programming if necessary.

Comment: Why would you do that in lieu of an actual synchronous transport?

Comment: In case the stability provided by the MQ or ESB compensates the effort. That's mainly the reason of the question.

Comment: If you want a robust synchronous transport, why not ask for that?

Comment: Since you already have java based web container, take a look at JAX-RS. The most implementations of JAX-RS server work as servlets.

Comment: @AnatolyG, App A doesn't see App B HTTP services.

Comment: @Andres, what do you mean by "doesn't see HTTP services"? App A cannot open a client socket to 80/8080/etc. port of App B? But in case of RMI you will need direct access to RMI ports. I'd definitely prefer JAX-RS over RMI if I have a web container. But, MQ hides physical location of all clients. It's a prop. But... :) you will have to manage an additional server. Not sure why we are talking about "Lightweight ESB", since the most of them are built over messaging. So, my choice is JAX-RS for direct synch calls or MQ, if I want to have flexible system topology :)

Comment: @AnatolyG by lightweight ESB I mean i.e. Spring Integration.

Comment: @Andres, regarding Spring. If you already have Tomcat/Jetty/etc. to host your web app, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667867/how-to-deploy-a-spring-integration-app-in-tomcat

Comment: I suggest re-tagging the question by adding [tag:integration]

Comment: And I suggest moving it to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding with definite answers. Discussions of high-level design concepts and best practices are more appropriate for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82990/228805) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every integration method has its advantages and disadvantages, and its really hard to propose one based only on what you have provided, but here is some hints:

- **Quick and Easy**: if you don't mind high coupling, and major changes in the applications are not expected (like DB engine, or replacing on with non-Java system), you can go with RMI or even DB Procedure calls.
- **Changes, Extendability and Scalability**: if the applications are expected to be changing more than rarely -and they tend to do-, ESBs or Message Queues would be great, since they would produce a loosely coupled architecture. This would also make room for extendability (like if you would have a new application C, that would need to invoke A or/and B)
- **HTTP Availability**: If HTTP communication is available between applications, Web Services is an excellent integration method.
- **Developers Knowledge**: What technologies you/the team are familiar with.

These are actually small hints, if you wish to go further in your research, I strongly recommend reading [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) the book.